# return mocked object for function defined in stream.map

Tags: unit-testing, java-8, mockito, junit4

I have a requirement to mock a dependent class that contains a function F< R,C >. 
**Class to be tested:**

```
class ClassToBeTested{
 @Autowired
 DependentClass dependentClass;

 public String doSomething(List<Person> list){
  ...
    list.stream().filter(p->p.getAge()>28).
    map(dependentClass.transformToEmployee).
    collect(Collectors.toList());
 ...
}
```

**DependentClass snippet:**

```
public Function<R, C> transformToEmployee = new Function() {
        public C apply(R rrd) {
            C cc = new C();
            if (rrd == null) {
                return cc;
            } else {
                ccInfo.setName(rrd.getFirstName()+ rrd.getLastName());
                ccInfo.setAge(rrd.getAge);
                return cc;
            }
        }
};
```

**Testing class snippet:**

```
@Test
public void testDoSomething(){
...
   Function<R, C> info =new TestHelper().transformToEmployee;
   info.apply(r); 
   when(mockedDependentClass.transformToEmployee).thenReturn(info);
...
}
```

And now I see this `exception` in console.
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.

Comment: Did you consider changing from field injection to constructor injection?

Comment: Why are you mocking this at all?  Just return the `Function`.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

`when(mockedDependentClass.transformToEmployee).thenReturn(info);`

to this:

`when(mockedDependentClass.transformToEmployee()).thenReturn(info);`

and that should solve your problem (notice the addition of `()` ).

Note that `mockedDependentClass` must be a mock, created either with `@Mock` or with `Mockito.mock(....)`